# Limite of data storage

Tags: database, limit

I want to create a very very very big sites on word press. But I don’t know what is the limit of data storage. Can Word press handle millions of users , for e learning courses website, with thousand of teachers and courses ?
Thanks !

Comment: the limiting factor for millions of users is not WordPress, it's your server hardware and bandwidth costs. Note that wordpress.com has hundreds of millions of users and serves tens of billions of pageviews from a single WordPress multisite installation, but has to do so sharded over many servers and data centres. Beyond a certain point it doesn't matter what software you're running on a machine, the sheer number of computers trying to open connections to it will overwhelm it before it can even load PHP/WP. Likewise hard drives only hold so much data